# Recoding Imitation

Tags: c++, server-side

Can someone imitate this code, or help me do it.  Its for a server side file, but it needs to be in C++ and I am not familiar with C++ at all.  Thanks in advance for any assistance!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

int main( int argc, char * argv[], char* env[]) {
int i = 0;

printf("Content-type: text/plain\n\n");

/* print query string only */
printf("%s\n",getenv("QUERY_STRING"));

/* print the whole environment */
while (env[i]) printf("%s\n",env[i++]);
return 0;
}
```

Comment: Is there any real point to this?  Pick up a C++ book and learn, you can't expect SO users to translate your code for the rest of your professional career.

Comment: chill.  I recognize I could shoot through a C++ book, but I know its almost the exact same and this is possibly the only time I'll need to use it for this particular job...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

C++ is essentially a superset of C, so this is already valid C++ code and should compile fine as such.

Comment: is there a way to recode it in C++ w/o using the 'scanf' or 'printf'

Comment: Well, no scanf here. But the printf lines could become, for example

Comment: std::cout << "Content-type: text/plain" << std::endl << std::endl;

Comment: thank you ernest, I recognize it was an "unworthy" (by SO standards) question, but I really needed to make sure it was the right way.  Thanks again!

Comment: for future reference what could I use in place of 'scanf'?

Comment: for example: // scanf("%s",quer); //

Comment: Something along the lines of "quer << std::cin", if quer is a  primitive like an int or float. Otherwise you might call std::cin.getLine() .

Comment: @Martin: you're on to something, but don't you mean \r\n\r\n ? The HTTP standard specifies CRLF line endings (although most implementations are pretty lenient about what they'll accept.)